# How do I drag a UIView subclass into Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios8, interface-builder

I'm following [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html) on adding a custom UIView sublcass to Interface Builder. They tell me to first label my UIView subclass. I have done that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface LoggedOutView : UIView
@end
```

Then they tell me to drag that UIView subclass from the Object Library in Interface Builder. I don't know where exactly is the Object Library. I am guessing it is the box in the lower right of the screen that shows all the standard UIViews. I search for my class in all 4 sections of that box and cannot find it.

[image]

Keep in mind that this is the first time I've ever used Interface Builder. I usually code all my UIView subclasses. However, I was forced to create a XIB for iOS 8's dynamic launch screens. (At least I think XIB's are required to flexibly layout launch screens on iOS 8).

Comment: You changed the question completely. LOL! My answer looks stupid now as you've completely changed the entire question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: you don't.

The launch screen does not load any code at all. It is merely a nib file that allows you to use auto layout to layout views on a screen. You can use text in labels, images, etc...

It's there so you can create launch screens for all different sizes of device and they will all be laid out correctly by AutoLayout.

You can't run any code though. Just use a plain `UIViewController` and standard UI elements `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, etc...

Comment: I've read quite a few tutorials on iOS 8's flexible launch screens and they always say I have to use the GUI editor to create a XIB file. How would I use a UIViewController subclass instead of a XIB file if I needed to use a math formula to layout a subview?

Comment: @Pwner I don't think you can with the launch screen. It isn't like a normal nib.

Comment: @Pwner to use a subclass of `UIView` in interface builder you first drag a `UIView` onto the canvas and give it a "Custom Subclass" in the properties inspector panel. But I don't think this will help with the launch screen.

Comment: I did that and I got the compile error "Launch screens may not use instances of LoggedOutView". So you're saying launch screen subviews must be laid out using a simple autoresize and can under no circumstance use a math formula?

Comment: @Pwner Yup, that error is what I was saying. You can't use anything but standard views. No code, no subclasses. The math formula that you're talking about... that's what AutoLayout is. AutoLayout uses the formula `y = mx + c` to layout views. I'm not sure what math you want to try to use but if it's more complex than that then you're stuck. Essentially, the launch screen is just an image. It's completely dumb. It can't use logic. It can't use code. All it can do is lay out views. The most logic you can get is AutoLayout.